# Combine absolute path and relative path to get a new absolute path

Tags: path, go

I'm writing a program in which one of the components must be able to take a path it is given (such as `/help/index.html`, or `/help/`) and a relative path based on that location, (such as `../otherpage/index.html`, or `sub/dir/of/help/`, or `help2.html`) and produce the absolute path implied by the relative path. Consider the following directory tree.

```
/
index.html
content.txt
help/
    help1.html
    help2.html
```

The file `index.html` contains a link like `help/help1.html`. The program is passed `/` or `/index.html`, and combines it with `help/help1.html` to get `/help/help1.html`.

Similarly, the file `/help/help1.html` has the link `../content.txt`, from which the program   needs to return `/content.txt`. Is there a reasonable way to do this?

Thank you. :)

**Edit:** Thank you to Stephen Weinberg! For everyone [from the future](http://xkcd.com/979/), here's the code I used.

```
func join(source, target string) string {
    if path.IsAbs(target) {
        return target
    }
    return path.Join(path.Dir(source), target)
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `path.Join` when used with `path.Dir` should do what you want. See http://golang.org/pkg/path/#example_Join for an interactive example.

```
path.Join(path.Dir("/help/help1.html"), "../content.txt")
```

This will return `/content.txt`.

Comment: Thank you! It didn't do quite what I wanted right off the bat, but I was able to wrap it in a tiny function using other path utilities. For anyone [from the future](http://xkcd.com/979/), here it is.

    func join(source, target string) string {
            if path.IsAbs(target) {
                return target
            }
        return path.Join(path.Dir(source), target)
    }

Comment: I see now it is not exactly what you wanted. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you again; I had to add an if statement due to absolute paths being interpreted strangely. I'm still unfamiliar with StackOverflow's particular brand of markdown, so I just added the code block up top.

Comment: @SashaCrofter, enclose blocks to be typeset as code in a pair of backticks (\`...\`). Note that you still can't have multi-line code blocks in comments, so your idea of amending your post is correct anyway.

Comment: this is broken: for example try to merge ```http://example.com/a/b``` with / : it should be ```http://example.com/``` but it returns ```http://example.com/a``` instead.

Answer (score 4):

[Stephen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13078343/1229237) is correct, but I wanted to add something to save future readers some time:

You should note functions within the [path package](https://golang.org/pkg/path/) assume the separator is `/`. When using the example above, I kept getting the output `.` since I had a Window's file path using `\`.

If you're not manipulating URLs, consider using the [filepath package](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/) which uses the OS's directory separator.

E.g. When running on Windows:

```
path.Dir("C:\\Users\\Darren\\Desktop\\file.txt")
filepath.Dir("C:\\Users\\Darren\\Desktop\\file.txt")
```

Returns:

```
.
C:\Users\Darren\Desktop
```