# Combine URL paths with path.Join()

Tags: url, go, path

Is there a way in Go to combine URL paths similarly as we can do with filepaths using `path.Join()`?

For example see e.g. [Combine absolute path and relative path to get a new absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13078314/772000).

When I use `path.Join("http://foo", "bar")`, I get `http:/foo/bar`.

See in [Golang Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/VPaiToD_XO).

Answer (score 159, accepted):

The function [path.Join](https://pkg.go.dev/path#Join) expects a path, not a URL. [Parse](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#Parse) the URL to get a path and join with that path:

```
u, err := url.Parse("http://foo")
if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }
u.Path = path.Join(u.Path, "bar.html")
s := u.String()
fmt.Println(s)  // prints http://foo/bar.html
```

Use the [url.JoinPath](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url@go1.19beta1#JoinPath) function in Go 1.19 or later:

```
s, err := url.JoinPath("http://foo", "bar.html")
if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }
fmt.Println(s) // prints http://foo/bar.html
```

Use [ResolveReference](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#URL.ResolveReference) if you are **resolving a URI reference from a base URL**. This operation is different from a simple path join: an absolute path in the reference replaces the entire base path; the base path is trimmed back to the last slash before the join operation.

```
base, err := url.Parse("http://foo/quux.html")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
ref, err := url.Parse("bar.html")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
u := base.ResolveReference(ref)
fmt.Println(u.String()) // prints http://foo/bar.html
```

Notice how quux.html in the base URL does not appear in the resolved URL.

Comment: This answer correctly explains the nuances between `u.String()` and `ResolveReference`

Comment: I believe this will be incorrect on Windows, where it'll join with "\" instead of "/"

Comment: @CodyA.Ray  The code works correctly on Windows.  The [path package](https://godoc.org/path) works with forward slash separated paths as stated in the first paragraphs of the package documentation.  The [path/filepath](https://godoc.org/path/filepath) package uses backslash on Windows, but that's not the package used in this answer.

Comment: @CeriseLimón but won't this mean the resulting URL looks like "http://foo\bar.html" when run on windows, instead of the expected "http://foo/bar.html"?

Comment: @CodyA.Ray
The path package works with forward slash separated paths on all platforms. The path generated by `path.Join(u.Path, "bar.html")` is `"/foo/bar.html"` on all platforms, including Windows. The path package [literally uses forward slash](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/9a0a150c9f50f920f35cc4d50ac3005503f44f2d/src/path/path.go#L158) in the Join implementation.

Comment: beware that `path.Join` strips all trailing slashes (since it calls `path.Clean` on the result before returning it) which can break URLs where trailing slashes have importance (a URL path does not necessarily have any relationship to a filesystem path, and so a trailing slash can affect how a URL is interpreted) -- the Go 1.19 solution explicitly addresses this and preserves a single trailing slash

Answer (score 44):

[ResolveReference() in net/url package](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#ResolveReference)

The accepted answer will not work for relative url paths containing file endings like .html or .img. The ResolveReference() function is the correct way to join url paths in go.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    u, err := url.Parse("../../..//search?q=dotnet")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    base, err := url.Parse("http://example.com/directory/")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(base.ResolveReference(u))
}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution for Go < 1.19 as it preserves a trailing slash

Answer (score 12):

A simple approach to this would be to trim the /'s you don't want and join. Here is an example func

```
func JoinURL(base string, paths ...string) string {
    p := path.Join(paths...)
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", strings.TrimRight(base, "/"), strings.TrimLeft(p, "/"))
}
```

Usage would be

```
b := "http://my.domain.com/api/"
u := JoinURL(b, "/foo", "bar/", "baz")
fmt.Println(u)
```

This removes the need for checking/returning errors

Comment: Downvoted: this will create an invalid URL if `base` has a query string or fragment.

Comment: @kbolino lol really. You are correct but the original example has no query string.

Comment: You can edit your answer to include a disclaimer about that caveat. I'd suggest the edit myself but my experience with doing that has shown that content-changing edits get rejected. Also, this question is the top search result in Google for "how to join urls in go", so the context is not limited to OP's example.

Answer (score 9):

In 1.19 there will be a new function in the standard library that solves this very neatly.

```
u, err := url.JoinPath("http://host/foo", "bar/")
```

https://go.dev/play/p/g422ockBq0q?v=gotip

Comment: Sounds nice on paper, but what if you have also query parameters?

Comment: @KamilDziedzic. In that case, I would use the URL type.  

https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#example-URL

Answer (score 8):

To join a `URL` with another `URL` or a path, there is [`URL.Parse()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL.Parse):

> ```
> func (u *URL) Parse(ref string) (*URL, error)
> ```
>
> Parse parses a URL in the context of the receiver. The provided URL
> may be **relative** or **absolute**. Parse returns `nil`, `err` on parse failure,
> otherwise its return value is the same as `ResolveReference`.

```
func TestURLParse(t *testing.T) {
    baseURL, _ := url.Parse("http://foo/a/b/c")

    url1, _ := baseURL.Parse("d/e")
    require.Equal(t, "http://foo/a/b/d/e", url1.String())

    url2, _ := baseURL.Parse("../d/e")
    require.Equal(t, "http://foo/a/d/e", url2.String())

    url3, _ := baseURL.Parse("/d/e")
    require.Equal(t, "http://foo/d/e", url3.String())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this utility function that works for my purposes:

```
func Join(basePath string, paths ...string) (*url.URL, error) {

    u, err := url.Parse(basePath)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("invalid url")
    }

    p2 := append([]string{u.Path}, paths...)

    result := path.Join(p2...)

    u.Path = result

    return u, nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/-QNVvyzacMM